# R determine if more than 1 value exists in a column, mutate concatenate if true

Tags: r, group-by, string-concatenation, dplyr

Couldn't quite find a solution to this one, looking for some guidance.

Here is a sample of a data set I have :

```
     ID   Rank    Date       Date2.      Group   Group2
1   5678   1    2000-01-01   2010-05-02    A      A
2   5678   2    2010-05-02   2010-05-02    A      A
3   1234   1    2000-01-01   2015-06-03    B      A&B
4   1234   2    2015-06-03   2015-06-03    A      A&B
```

I would like to group by ID and determine if multiple values exist for that ID in the Group column. And if so, concatenate them together.

Group2 is the desired output based on grouping ID and seeing if multiple values exist in Group. I am using dplyr but am unsure where to go from here:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Group2 = if else(?))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the easiest way is the `unique` function. This function creates a vector with the distinct values of the vector given.

```
> df %>%
   group_by(ID)%>%
   mutate(Group2=paste(sort(unique(Group)),
                       collapse="&"))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Group Group2
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
1  5678 A     A     
2  5678 A     A     
3  1234 B     A&B   
4  1234 A     A&B
```

Answer (score 1):

Going on with your code I would try:

```r
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Group2 = ifelse(n_distinct(Group) == 1, as.character(Group), paste0(sort(Group), collapse = "&")))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  Rank Date       Date2.     Group Group2
  <int> <int> <fct>      <fct>      <fct> <chr> 
1  5678     1 2000-01-01 2010-05-02 A     A     
2  5678     2 2010-05-02 2010-05-02 A     A     
3  1234     1 2000-01-01 2015-06-03 B     A&B   
4  1234     2 2015-06-03 2015-06-03 A     A&B
```

Comment: thanks! I do get an error with this code ```Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"```

Comment: Yes! I updated my answer. Error came from being `Group` a factor

Comment: Note that now I use `ifelse` instead of `if_else`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest next approach:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(ID,Group) %>%
  #Identify unique elements
  mutate(NUnique=n_distinct(Group)) %>%
  mutate(Group2=ifelse(NUnique>1,paste0(Group,collapse = '&'),Group))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  Rank Date       Date2.     Group NUnique Group2
  <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>   <int> <chr> 
1  1234     2 2015-06-03 2015-06-03 A           2 A&B   
2  1234     1 2000-01-01 2015-06-03 B           2 A&B   
3  5678     1 2000-01-01 2010-05-02 A           1 A     
4  5678     2 2010-05-02 2010-05-02 A           1 A
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(5678L, 5678L, 1234L, 1234L), Rank = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), Date = c("2000-01-01", "2010-05-02", "2000-01-01", 
"2015-06-03"), Date2. = c("2010-05-02", "2010-05-02", "2015-06-03", 
"2015-06-03"), Group = c("A", "A", "B", "A")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Group2 := paste(sort(unique(Group)), collapse="&"), ID]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(5678L, 5678L, 1234L, 1234L), Rank = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), Date = c("2000-01-01", "2010-05-02", "2000-01-01", 
"2015-06-03"), Date2. = c("2010-05-02", "2010-05-02", "2015-06-03", 
"2015-06-03"), Group = c("A", "A", "B", "A")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
within(df,Group2 <- ave(Group,ID,FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x))==1,x,paste0(x,collapse = "&"))))
```

giving

```
    ID Rank       Date     Date2. Group Group2
1 5678    1 2000-01-01 2010-05-02     A      A
2 5678    2 2010-05-02 2010-05-02     A      A
3 1234    1 2000-01-01 2015-06-03     B    B&A
4 1234    2 2015-06-03 2015-06-03     A    B&A
```